# ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss Global CSS cannot be imported from file

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to solve this problem.

You got this suddenly, and I still haven't found a solution!

my app_tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import React from "react";

// styles
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
import "tippy.js/dist/tippy.css";
import "tippy.js/animations/perspective-subtle.css";
import "tippy.js/themes/light.css";
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
```

// components

Comment: please put your last line of code into code fences. thank you.

Comment: Try remove ```"../node_modules/"``` part. It should be: ```import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";```

Comment: change question title by removing special characters